# How to join two lists using REST API sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I have two lists with look up column. How do i join two lists using REST API call.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You use the [$expand](http://www.threewill.com/using-the-expand-odata-query-option-in-sharepoint-2013/) query option.

For example, you have two lists: `ListA` and `ListB`.  `ListA` has two fields: `Field1` and `Field2`.  `ListB` has three fields: `FieldA`, `FieldB` and `LookupField`.  `LookupField` looks up to `ListA`.  REST query should be as such:

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ListB')/items?$select=FieldA,FieldB,LookupField/Field1,LookupField/Field2&$expand=LookupField
```

You select the fields from the list by adding their internal name to the `$select` query option, and you select fields from the lookup list by using the format `LookupField/FieldFromLookupList`, and then you add the lookup field to the `$expand` query option.

Comment: How do i get current list fields with $expand

Comment: For fields from the child list (the one with the lookup field), simply add them to the `$select` portion.  For fields from the parent (the lookup list), add them to the `$select` portion in the format `LookupField/FieldFromLookupList`, where `LookupField` is the internal name of the lookup field in the child list (all field names must be the internal names).

Comment: Means correct me if am wrong, I can directly specify the child list field name in $select portion, If i need parent list fields i should use lookupfield/fieldname right ?

Comment: Fields from the list that contains the lookup field can be directly specified in the $select portion.  Fields from the list being looked up to have to be specified using `lookupfield/fieldname`.

Comment: See edits, I hope it explains it better.

Comment: Ya it is working for me thank you so much for quick answer