# How do i get current list fields along with lookup field using $expand REST API Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I have two lists list1 and list2. Am having lookup column in list2 say List1_Id . With $expand option am able to get the fields from list1. Issue is how do i get List2 fields.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question is a follow-up to the answer given in this question.  http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/145925/how-to-join-two-lists-using-rest-api-sharepoint-2013

Comment: I changed my answer in the other question to answer this one as well