# Using SPServices operation 'GetListItems' how to construct a CAML Query joining two lists?

Tags: 2013, javascript, spservices, caml

Using SP2013 - JavaScript - $().SPServices() - operation 'GetListItems' - how would I construct a CAML query that will join two lists where list 'A' has a reference to list 'B' specifically having a where clause on a text field in list 'A' as well as a where clause on a text field in list 'B'?

For example, list 'BookTitles' has a reference to list 'Authors'.  I would like to pull back all book titles having the title 'Absence' and Author 'John Freeman'.  Knowing the list of Book Titles has more than one entry for the title 'Absence' given this title is given to 7 different stories - each a story having the same title but a different author - I would expect my result set to be a single row - the book title 'Absence' related specifically to author 'John Freeman'.

Comment: AFAIK, the CAML Join only works server side. You have to make 2 separate calls to the lists, store the result sets, then parse through the results looking for what you need.

Comment: Not sure about CAML join but this is supported in REST api. You might want to give that a try.

Comment: @uberz91 - please elaborate.  Using $().SPServices() which I believe is SOAP based - not REST.  Ultimately (as seen by fiddler) the call is to lists.asmx - which is a standard SOAP endpoint...

Comment: Yes. What I meant was, you could try another approach instead of getlistitems. In REST, it is much easier to execute a join.

Comment: @uberz91 - example please...

Comment: Check this: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/145925/how-to-join-two-lists-using-rest-api-sharepoint-2013

Comment: @Eric - thanks for the advice - please restructure your comments as an actual answer and I will award you the answer.  I implemented your suggestion and it works fine.  Because the lists have a many-to-many cardinality I now have many web service calls which is not great, but it seems fast enough.  It is truly unfortunate a single query cannot be submitted using SPService() GetListItems #weak

Comment: Remember, it isn't SPServices fault, Marc is only doing what the web services allow him to do. Marc is wrapping the web services to be able to use them more easily and provide other value.

Comment: @Eric - your right - I squarely blame M$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CAML joins, to my knowledge, only work on the server side. To mimic that on the client side, you have to make several calls, storing the results in objects or arrays, parsing through that, and making further calls.

This isn't a limitation of SPServices, but the underlying web services themselves.