# How to collect information from Subsites?

Tags: 2013, content-type, content-query-web-part, blog, sub-site

As I wrote, I'm looking for some suggestions about how to do the next thing:

This is the scenario: I set a Site Collection up with several blogs as subsites. What I want to do is to show on the main page of the site collection some entries from these subsites.

To do this, I created a Content Type with some Columns as "IsVisible on home" for the blog's entries. I also use to show the information a "Content Query Web Part" where I set the condition to be showed on the home page. This WebPart also allows me to configure css styles, setting the ItemStyle.XSL file. But the point is that I don't really know how to show the number of comment for every blog entry. Can someone give me a clue?

PD. I'm using Sharepoint 2013.

Comment: SP 2010 or 2013?

Comment: Sharepoint 2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blogs and Comments are two **different lists** in the Subsites.

So the CQWP only gets you the Blogs

*You could try quering on a common contenttype to get everything..

but it is going to be some hairy XSLT*

SP2013 DisplayTemplates (JavaScript programming) instead of the CQWP may be a more helpfull approach. XSLT is something for the past.

http://en.share-gate.com/blog/useful-sharepoint-display-template

Will get you started on displaying the Blog items,

But you will require some more complex JSOM/Javascript code as for each item, you have to dig back into that subsite to retrieve the corresponding items from the Comments list.

Maybe using a REST call can help in joining lists

[How to join two lists using REST API sharepoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/145925/how-to-join-two-lists-using-rest-api-sharepoint-2013)

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. At the end, I did almost the same because I'm using the Rest API but I created my own request-response, because I didn't know that. Anyway, your reply is really useful for me, thank you again.

Comment: Tnx. You could share your code here (if you want) as an update in your question so everyone is helped