# $expand a property that is inside a folder

Tags: 2010, rest, folder

I have 2 lists, ParentList and ChildList. The items in ParentList are in folders. Child list has a lookup field pointing to an item in ParentList. When I attempt to run the following query:

```
 /_vti_bin/ListData.svc/ChildList?$expand=ParentList
```

The parent object is not expanded and returns a null object. It seems that $expand is not recursive. This killed us. Is there any way around this limitation?

Example response when trying to expand:

```
<link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/ParentList" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="ParentList" href="ChildList(1)/ParentList">
    <m:inline />
</link>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this type of query:

```
/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/ChildList?$expand=lookupcolumn_name$select=FieldA,FieldB
```

You will get some reference from @wjervis's [answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/145925/how-to-join-two-lists-using-rest-api-sharepoint-2013).

Comment: This works in 2013, but not 2010.